# Does unclosed/No return python daemon thread cause memory leaks?

Tags: python, multithreading, memory-leaks, kill-process

I am new to python, so most of the code is lifted from the internet.
I have this code which I had run in python:

```
def see1():
   while True:
    #Non returning some memory occupying code

see1=threading.Thread(target=see)
see1.daemon=True
see1.start()
```

So, My computer had been slowing gradually even after I close the application(Terminal). I believe this is caused due to the memory leak of this which may probably be running in the background?.
I want to know two things:

1. Will closing the terminal in which the program is running, kill this thread too? Therefore this is not the cause of the slowing down.
2. If closing the terminal window does not kill the thread, then how do I kill it?

Comment: A daemon thread is just one that can't keep the process alive. If the process dies, the thread goes with it (as it is simply *part* of the process). Whether closing the terminal kills the process depends on how your terminal is configured, and is out of your program's control.

Comment: @chepner But in theory isn't a thread as good as a parallel process itself? Therefore independent of the calling process?

Comment: No, not at all. A process has to actively switch between two threads; the thread library takes care of those details to make it *seem* like they are running in parallel, but they are really just running *concurrently*. True parallelism requires two processes (and an operating system that can schedule them on separate processors).

Comment: @chepner Agreed. In which case, The threading module in python is just a high speed time multiplexer? And how do I know if closing the terminal closes the process too? Like, how do I know how it is configured? Thanks a ton